# Power & Sleep Management

Tags: 12.10, power-management, battery, sleep

I'm running 12.10 *with xmonad*.

Trying to ensure that the right things happen when I close laptop lid, etc. I see Internet search results for similar issues that mostly point towards gnome-power-manager. I have the package installed, but `gnome-power-manager` is not in my path anywhere.

The behavior I'm looking for is as following:

- Sleep on lid close
- Awaken on lid open
- Turn off screen after 10 idle minutes
- **Most importantly**, have better battery life. I'm supposed to be getting 9 hours and I haven't seen the battery life estimate above 2.5 hours yet.

Any tips on where to look or how to configure this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

To set up the Laptop Lid Close Action you have to install Advanced Setting (or the Gnome Tweak Tool).I suppose you have installed it ( if not you can do that from USC (Ubuntu Software Center) under either tweak or Advanced Settings.), so here what you have to do,

Press the super button and type in tweak or advanced and choose the Advanced Settings. When it opens choose the shell tab;

[image]

choose you desired on both on AC and on battery

---

I dont know if xmonad effets this but you may even need to check your settings in

**/etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/com.ubuntu.enable-hibernate.pkla**

Make sure you have two settings in there

[Enable hibernate by default in upower]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.upower.hibernate
ResultActive=**yes**

[Enable hibernate by default in logind]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate
ResultActive=**yes**

You can read more about the file and its settings [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-control-center/+bug/1194328).

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

You can see the files installed by the `gnome-power-manager` package by executing `dpkg -L gnome-power-manager`.

Your PATH is used by your shell to find commands to execute. Packages can install files anywhere they need to. Your command line never needs to execute power management commands.

I suggest that you take a look at the `pm-utlls` package. It does most of the lid close/open stuff.

Comment: It looks like `gnome-power-manager` only provides `gnome-power-statistics`. The statistics I see in that are pretty depressing -- it's depleting much faster than I'd anticipate. But I guess that's the subject of another question, maybe. I have `jupiter` running, I was under the impression that was supposed to greatly extend battery life. Any pointers?

Comment: You could run `top` and see what's eating CPU time, or look into "process accounting", see `man -k accounting`.  Look at the scripts in `dpkg -L pm-utils`, and make sure that they work on your machine.

Comment: I see quite a large number of scripts in `/usr/lib/pm-utils/` but none of their titles have anything to do with laptop lid closing. `pm-hibernate` and `pm-suspend` work well. I turned on a bunch of the PowerTOP optimizations, either that or something else seemed to have improved its life a little bit. Thanks for your help so far!

Answer (score 0):

[I run i3 without any other desktop managers (e.g, gnome), so it may work in your case]

comment out the screenblank line and add command to suspend below it in **/etc/acpi/lid.sh**, as shown below:

```
#. /usr/share/acpi-support/screenblank
/usr/sbin/pm-suspend
```

*man xset* for your screen blank and power save settings (controls the blank time, etc).  *xset q* to see what things are set to.  If you **don't** want blanking (i.e., watching a movie) then you want to *xset s off* and *xset -dpms*.

When I open my lid the computer is still suspended.  Pressing any keyboard key resumes very rapidly (even on a slow computer).  I would love for the lid to trigger wakeup but have not yet figured out how to do it.