# Whenever i suspend when i resume my screen is just black

Tags: screen, suspend

I am running Ubuntu 12.04 on a Sony Vaio machine. System has ran Ubuntu for over 18months and never has this happened before. COnstantly keep update with all updates, however the last half dozen times i have put it into suspend (just shut lid) when i come to wake it up all i have is a totally black screen. No mouse cursor- just blackness!

Can anyone help please? Thanks

Comment: I think this link could help you solve your problem. You should look for **all** the provided solutions on that page, some of them seem to be quite ok.

http://askubuntu.com/questions/213399/power-sleep-management

Answer (score 0):

happens to me to. is said to be becuase you changed power settings from default. For me the black screen goes away when i move the mouse or press a button. Does this work for you too?